# FTP Path converted into C drive location path, want to access FTP files - Dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to access the FTP path and files like - //corp/Test/Test.txt but getting below error.
In c# console(Dot net 6) getting a system.IODirectoryNot found exception 'C:Users\Test.txt'

above ftp path is being converted into C drive path and giving a error.

please help, Thank you!

Comment: But `//corp/Test/Test.txt` isn't a typical FTP file path if you read https://superuser.com/questions/1103547/how-to-form-ftp-url-using-absolute-path-in-windows . You'd better share some of your code to help others understand what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

What is your code on providing the path? Have you tried verbatim identifier `@"c:\Users\Test.txt"`?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-7.0

It seems the path has wrong input since 'C:Users\Test.txt' is definitely a wrong path.

Please provide more details

Comment: I want to access FTP path and files located in path :- \\corp\dfs\Test.txt , I am passing this FTP path as a parameter and while accessing this path in C# code this path converted into c drive path like - C:\users .  getting a system.IODirectoryNot found exception. But if i hard code the path , it is working fine

Comment: @abhi try to put a breakpoint on a statement just before the exception happens and run with debugger, what is the exact string with path?

Answer (score 1):

Your path is most likely incorrect. The format the you are specifying it in might be slightly wrong.

Using [string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) should help - these can be used by using the "@" symbol before the string.

Once you have correctly provided the path, it should work e.g.

```
var path = @"//corp/Test/Test.txt";
File.ReadAllText(path);
```